# Ubuntu 11.04 Is not Supporting My HP Pavilion Computer

Tags: unity, 11.04, unity-2d, hp-pavilion

I have upgraded my Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04 twice,But after Installing it's giving a message "You system doesn't support 2D unity Login under Ubuntu Classic Desktop" After logging in Ubuntu Classic desktop for booting OS it's taking about 5 mins to boot-up, and even after booting it's not working properly it's just when i press on any menu it's get flickering effect so it means my system doesn't support Ubuntu 11.04 
My system Configuration 
HP-Pavilion 
P-4 
2GB RAM 
250GB H/D
Intel Extreme Graphics Card

Comment: Are you sure it is "unity 2D"? Unity 2D is not installed by default, and you should not be getting that message.

Try "Ubuntu Classic (No Effect)", and tell us if it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install your video card driver, after that Ubuntu shall show Unit interface.